# updating python3 tkinter label not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I can manually update label and entry if i clicked the manual button, but if i clicked the auto button... the console show the random number but the widgets are not updating.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

def manual_settxt():
    for t in range(0,3):
        rd = random.randrange(1,100)
        labelWidgets[t].configure(text=rd)
        entryWidgets[t].delete(0,END)
        entryWidgets[t].insert(0,rd)

def auto_settxt():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        for t in range(0,3):
            rd = random.randrange(1,100)
            print(rd)
            labelWidgets[t].configure(text=rd)
            entryWidgets[t].delete(0,END)
            entryWidgets[t].insert(0,rd)

root = Tk()

namesInput = [1,2,3]
entryWidgets = []
labelWidgets = []

for i in range(0, len(namesInput)):
    labelWidgets.append(Label(root,text=namesInput[i],justify='center'))
    entryWidgets.append(Entry(root,width=5,justify='center'))
    labelWidgets[-1].grid(row=i+1,column=0)
    entryWidgets[-1].grid(row=i+1,column=1)

b1 = Button(root, text = "Manual", command=manual_settxt)
b1.grid(row=4,column=0)

b2 = Button(root, text = "Auto", command=auto_settxt)
b2.grid(row=4,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: avoid using `sleep()` with tkinter GUI. Use `after()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an infinite loop. Delete `while True`. 
I refactored some code: used Thread for non-blocking functionality.
Try this

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
from threading import Thread

def manual_settxt():
    for index in range(3):
        rd = random.randrange(1,100)
        labelWidgets[index].configure(text=rd)
        entryWidgets[index].delete(0,END)
        entryWidgets[index].insert(0,rd)

def job():
    for index in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        rd = random.randrange(1,100)
        print(rd)
        labelWidgets[index].configure(text=rd)
        entryWidgets[index].delete(0,END)
        entryWidgets[index].insert(0,rd)


def auto_settxt():
    Thread(target=job).start()

root = Tk()

namesInput = [1,2,3]
entryWidgets = []
labelWidgets = []

for index, name in enumerate(namesInput):

    labelWidgets.append(Label(root, text=name, justify='center'))
    entryWidgets.append(Entry(root, width=5, justify='center'))

    labelWidgets[-1].grid(row=index+1,column=0)
    entryWidgets[-1].grid(row=index+1,column=1)

b1 = Button(root, text = "Manual", command=manual_settxt)
b1.grid(row=4,column=0)

b2 = Button(root, text = "Auto", command=auto_settxt)
b2.grid(row=4,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nikolay... I need the "while True" because I will be scraping the webpage for data changes to update the widgets. And it need to run continously.

Comment: Nikolay...  Appending back the "while" ... then it wont update the widgets.

Comment: If you don't exit the loop -> you will block the GUI, and it will freeze. I hope, that you understand how gui works.
You start parser in other thread. It would be great idea.

Comment: avoid using `sleep()` with tkinter GUI. Use `after()` instead.

Comment: Follow Mike advice and avoid blocking functions and infinite loops.

Comment: Using Thread is killing a fly with a bazooka.  See the after() code below, although you want to delete the line "root.after(1000, auto_settxt)" at the bottom because you want to start the function only when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I use "root.after" and the script seems to be working fine.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

def manual_settxt():
    for index in range(3):
        rd = random.randrange(1,100)
        labelWidgets[index].configure(text=rd)
        entryWidgets[index].delete(0,END)
        entryWidgets[index].insert(0,rd)

def auto_settxt():
        for index in range(3):
            rd = random.randrange(1,100)
            print(rd)
            labelWidgets[index].configure(text=rd)
            entryWidgets[index].delete(0,END)
            entryWidgets[index].insert(0,rd)
        root.after(1000, auto_settxt)

root = Tk()

namesInput = [1,2,3]
entryWidgets = []
labelWidgets = []

for index, name in enumerate(namesInput):

    labelWidgets.append(Label(root, text=name, justify='center'))
    entryWidgets.append(Entry(root, width=5, justify='center'))

    labelWidgets[-1].grid(row=index+1,column=0)
    entryWidgets[-1].grid(row=index+1,column=1)

b1 = Button(root, text = "Manual", command=manual_settxt)
b1.grid(row=4,column=0)

b2 = Button(root, text = "Auto", command=auto_settxt)
b2.grid(row=4,column=1)

root.after(1000, auto_settxt)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The auto_settext() is called from a button press, so the "root.after(1000, auto_settxt)" on the next to last line should be deleted.

Comment: thank curly...  my mistake,, May I know what this means " 
 labelWidgets[-1] "

Comment: You can answer your own question, print labelWidgets, and then print labelWidgets[-1] (and didn't it originally come from __your code__).  Also, to be complete you should have an exit or quit_the_program button which calls a function.  This function calls after_cancel() so as to not leave an after hanging  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm  The function then calls root.quit() to exit the program.

Comment: The " print labelWidgets, and then print labelWidgets[-1] " when i tried to "print('minus ' , labelWidgets[-1])" and "print('num ' , labelWidgets)" ... I do not understand the return printed message. I want to know why must we set [-1], I will append "root.quit()" and thanks Curly,,, wished I could give you a vote.